# Subdomain to remote server folder DNS

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain

I'm running a site on an apache server named `www.example.com` which has `sub.example.com` subdomain. Also I have a vps, which is accessable through `x.x.x.x` IP adress. `sub.example.com` is redirected to `x.x.x.x/example` with htaccess So I can reach my files on `x.x.x.x/example` through `sub.example.com`.

Everything is ok with this. But I want to solve this issue with DNS. How can I achieve that?

I'm using cpanel on www.example.com.

I searched a lot about that issue and find some information. I just know I have to create an A record for subdomain pointing `x.x.x.x` Also I read about i should set virtual server on apache. But I'm not fully aware of apache settings. One last thing is I want my subdomain to point only `x.x.x.x/example`. So I need a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel under domains, there is an option for subdomain. You basically give cpanel the subdomain (sub) and the folder you want it to point to (/public_html/example). Then hit create. Here is a video walkthrough.

http://www.everymanhosting.com/cpanel-tutorials/create-subdomains.php

Comment: I guess, you got me all wrong.